# How to create flip animation in android?

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper

I have a tablelayout with multiple viewFlipper in each square. What I want is whichever viewflipper i touch, the view should flip. Everything is working fine but what I need is [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) kind of animation.

The animator files given there cannot be used in `viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);`. We need to use anim for it not animator.

Android do give some built in animations but all of them are fade, slide etc but not flip. I think flipping is one of the most used animations, why isn't android providing one in default or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this. Although there is a library but you need not used the whole library just for flipping views. check out this [tutorial](http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/a-property-animation-tutorial.html#tutorial_app). Basically you create an animator xml as shown in the android guide in question. Then you can use it to animate any object not only views. Just use it like this

```
 Animator flipAnimator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this,R.animator.card_flip_left_in);
 flipAnimator.setTarget(cardView);
 flipAnimator.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try github library - [Flip 3D View](https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/).

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I managed to solve it using android built in Animator class.